# How to fix the photo selector 'request access'

Tags: swift

I am trying to add a photo selector request access. How can I trigger and present the image picker controller if access on request(first time) is granted first? Note: The .info file is already set and everything runs smooth...

I am working with an image view with these properties:

```
lazy var projectImageView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "select_photo_empty")) //Default Image View asking for photo...

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectPhoto)))

    return imageView

}()
```

At first hand I tried this... But the code doesn't run..

```
 func checkStatus(){

            let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

            switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:

                print("Access is granted by user")

            case .notDetermined: PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                (newStatus) in print("status is \(newStatus)")

                if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {

                    print("success")

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("Trying to open photos")

                }
                })

            case .restricted:
                print("User do not have access to photo album.")

            case .denied:
                print("User has denied the permission.")
            }

}


 @objc func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

// Local variable inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

    print(info)

    if let editedImage = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage)] as? UIImage {

        projectImageView.image = editedImage

    } else if let originalImage = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {

        projectImageView.image = originalImage

    }

    setupCircularImageStyle()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's the entire code with the required blocks:

```
 func checkStatus(){

            let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

            switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:

                print("Access is granted by user")

            case .notDetermined: PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                (newStatus) in print("status is \(newStatus)")

                if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {

                    print("success")

                }
                })

            case .restricted:
                print("User do not have access to photo album.")
            case .denied:
                print("User has denied the permission.")
            }

}


@objc func handleSelectPhoto(){

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("Trying to open photos")

}


 @objc func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

  // Local variable inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
  let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

    print(info)

    if let editedImage = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage)] as? UIImage {

        projectImageView.image = editedImage

    } else if let originalImage = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {

        projectImageView.image = originalImage

    }

    setupCircularImageStyle()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Again, I would like to present the access request for the first time to the user, but having trouble setting the 'checkStatus' function...

Comment: what the current problem ? where you call `checkStatus` ?

Comment: yes, tried to do it on the didfinishPickingMediaWithInfo function, but misbehaves...first opens the image picker and then asks for permission